# Why doesn't router forward IP packets in a local network?

Tags: windows, networking, ip, router, local-area-network

I've got two hosts in one local network: 192.168.31.10 and 192.168.31.11, their gateway both are 192.168.31.1.

The route table on 192.168.31.10 is as below:

```
0.0.0.0   0.0.0.0   192.168.31.1  192.168.31.10
192.168.31.0 255.255.255.0 On-Link 192.168.31.10
```

I can understand the route table.

What I can't understand is that if I delete the second route rule, host 10 can't ping host 11.
In my guess, the first route rule should take effect then the router forward IP packets to host 11, but it didn't. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Routers route packets _between_ networks, not from a network back to the same network. For a destination on the same network as the source, the source does not send the traffic to the router. The source will mask both the source and destination addresses to see if they are on different networks. If the networks are different, then the source creates a frame for the router, otherwise it creates a frame for the destination host.

Comment: @RonMaupin You mean the second route helps the host to know its network id?

Comment: No, the host knows its own network from its configured address and mask (address AND mask = network, do the same with both the source and destination addresses and compare the results). The second route tells the host how to reach its own network to try to find the destination host, and, yes, the router too because it is on that network.

Comment: @RonMaupin Without second route, the host knows the source and destination are on same network , but it does not know the next hop address. Is that right?

Comment: A host must explicitly be told how to reach any network. If it does not know how to reach a network, it drops the packet. Remember that you may have several interfaces on one host, and the host needs to know which to use. The second route tells the host how to reach that network though that interface, The first route tells it that if there are no more specific routes, send it to the router.

Comment: @RonMaupin But there is the first route,  so the host acturlly knows which interface to use. What really matters is that the router does not forward them and it should not forward them. Do I get your point?

Comment: No, the first route is to a specific host (router) not the interface to use to get to that host.

Comment: @RonMaupin I captured packets with Wireshark. It looks like the host 10 did send packets to host 11 while only the first route exists. In fact, I can still visit my gateway without the second route. Those are not in line with what you said. I am totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that without the second route, your computer does not know how to find the router which is on the same subnet, so it can't send out the traffic.

Answer (score -2):

I think I've found the answer. It's very clear in RFC1918 section 3:
"Because private addresses have no global meaning, routing information
   about private networks shall not be propagated on inter-enterprise
   links, and packets with private source or destination addresses
   should not be forwarded across such links. Routers in networks not
   using private address space, especially those of Internet service
   providers, are expected to be configured to reject (filter out)
   routing information about private networks. If such a router receives
   such information the rejection shall not be treated as a routing
   protocol error. ".

Comment: This answer is incorrect in as much as it does not apply to your problem. The same issue would happen if you had non rfc1918 ips

Comment: @davidgo But it's not like what you said. I can still explore outside websites without the second route.

Comment: @davidgo It's a very sample local network with a soho router.